# Why my bundle products return a different SKU?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, sku, bundle

I'm getting the SKU from my Bundle product and the products associated too, but the result bellow showed up.

```
Bundle Product SKU: BundleQA-GT-5AHG30008P
Simple Product SKU: GT-5AHG30008P
```

It's concatenating the bundle product SKU with the simple product SKU to show as the bundle product SKU, it must be just `BundleQA`.

How could I solve it?

Comment: Is there a way to default Dynamic SKU to "No" when you create them? When I try to create a Bundle, it defaults Dynamic SKU to "Yes", even though the attribute is set to Default to "No".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because the product was created using the Dynamic SKU option. You just need to disable it and refresh the page.

[image: Magento2 Bundle products using dynamic SKU]

So, it's going to return:

```
Bundle Product SKU: BundleQA
Simple Product SKU: GT-5AHG30008P
```

Answer (score 0):

Store > attributes - Product > sku_type - Dynamic SKU > Advanced Attribute Properties > Default Value - Yes or No > to what you want it to be?

">" = click,
"-" = look for